# In C# how can i check if T is of type IInterface and cast to that if my object supports that interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

In C#, I have a function that passes in `T` using `generics` and I want to run a check to see if `T` is an `object` that implements a `interface` and if so call one of the `methods` on that `interface`.

I don't want to have `T` constraints to only be of that Type.  Is it possible to do this?

For example:

```
public class MyModel<T> : IModel<T> where T : MyObjectBase
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetRecords()
    {
        var entities = Repository.Query<T>();
        if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            //Filterme is a method that takes in IEnumerable<IFilterable>
            entities = FilterMe(entities));
        }
        return entities;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TResult> FilterMe<TResult>(IEnumerable<TResult> linked) where TResult : IFilterable
    {
        var dict = GetDict();
        return linked.Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id));
    }
 }
```

The error that I am getting is:

**Error 21  The type 'TResult' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'FilterMe(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TResult' to 'IFilterable'.**

Comment: _NEVER_ place a generic method within a generic class where the generic type parameter of the method has the same name as the one of the class, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Jeff - that was actually a typo . . i have updated the question

Comment: why would only some class implement IFilterable? Why not all class have filtering with empty implementation?

Comment: @Akash because many tables are not filterable and should be showing global shared data while others get filtered down to a specific team

Comment: Non filterable table can have empty implementation, the best design will be to have a common base class with virtual method for filtering, virtual filter method does not do anything for non filterable classes and filterable classes can override filtering method. Infact that is true object oriented design.

Comment: Does your interface `IFilterable` contain any members, or do simply use it to mark your class as filterable?

Comment: could you please provide an `T` Example Class both situations

Comment: Does your method FilterMe has to be public? And does GetRecords has to return IQuerable? Or does FilterMe has to return IEnumerable? If not, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The missing piece is `Cast<>()`:

```
if(typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
    entities = FilterMe(entities.Cast<IFilterable>()).AsQueryable().Cast<T>();
}
```

Note the use of `Cast<>()` to convert the entities list to the correct subtype. This cast would fail unless `T` implements `IFilterable`, but since we already checked that, we know that it will.

Comment: but this still doesn't compile

Comment: @leora: What's the compile error? You probably need to cast the result of `FilterMe` back to `T` with another call to `Cast<T>()`

Comment: I get the error stating that T must have the constraint IFilterable but that is what i am trying to avoid

Comment: I added the FilterMe code to make it easier to see if you can figure out what i am doing wrong

Comment: You shouldn't need the constraint. Can you show me the exact error you get when you use `entities = FilterMe(entities.Cast<IFilterable>()).Cast<T>()`?

Comment: @leora: what error message do you get when you use my code? There's no way you'd get the error message you posted in your question if you used my code.

Comment: Ah . .i didn't paste the separate cast . . so it seems to work which i great . .  my one question is how much of a performance hit will i tke with these 2 casts compared to just creating a separate method?

Comment: @leora: avoiding casting will always perform better, but it depends on how often you are calling this function and what your performance needs are. When in doubt, measure and see if it makes a difference that you care about.

Comment: Why dont you try dynamic variable? Assuming type implements method, just call it.

Comment: @siride I take that as an insult.

Comment: Siride's answer is almost correct.  It is missing a `.AsQueryable()` before the `.Cast<T>`.  The returned IEnumerable is  not implicitly castable to an IQueryable. (You could place it after, but you'll get a suspicious cast warning).

Answer (score 18):

```
if (typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

This checks whether a variable of type `IMyInterface` can be assigned from an instance of type `T`.

Comment: that works great but how can i then call the method on the interface if that method is not on all T constrained object . . If i try calling it . . i still get the "You have to remove this constraint error"

Comment: I added some code to the question to make it clear what i am trying to do

Comment: You should post your class. I doubt your class has some of a inappropriate constraint.

Comment: I added the FilterMe code to see if you can determine why this won't compile

Answer (score 3):

If you have a generic-type parameter that may or may not implement `IFoo`, it's possible to `as` cast it to a storage location of type `IFoo`; if you do that, you may pass it to any method which expects an `IFoo`, as well as any method that expects a generic parameter constrained to `IFoo`, but you will lose all generic type information if you do that--the parameter will be passed as type `IFoo`.  Among other things, this will mean that if your original object was a structure, it will be boxed.

If you wish to test whether a generic parameter type implements `IFoo` and call a method that takes a generic-constrained `IFoo` if it does, while keeping the original generic type (this could be useful if the type is a struct, and could be necessary if the type is being passed to a generic method which has both `IFoo` and `IBar` constraints and the things one might want to pass do not share any single common supertype), it will be necessary to use Reflection.

For example, suppose one wants to have a method `Zap` which takes a generic `ref` parameter, calls `Dispose` on it if it implements `IDisposable`, and clears it out.  If the parameter is an `IDisposable` class type, a null test should be performed as an atomic operation with clearing out the parameter.

```
public static class MaybeDisposer
{
    static class ClassDisposer<T> where T : class,IDisposable
    {
        public static void Zap(ref T it)
        {
            T old_it = System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref it, null);
            if (old_it != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disposing class {0}", typeof(T));
                old_it.Dispose();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Class ref {0} already null", typeof(T));
        }
    }
    static class StructDisposer<T> where T : struct,IDisposable
    {
        public static void Zap(ref T it)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing struct {0}", typeof(T));
            it.Dispose();
            it = default(T);
        }
    }
    static class nonDisposer<T>
    {
        public static void Zap(ref T it)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type {0} is not disposable", typeof(T));
            it = default(T);
        }
    }
    class findDisposer<T>
    {
        public static ActByRef<T> Zap = InitZap;
        public static void InitZap(ref T it)
        {
            Type[] types = {typeof(T)};
            Type t;
            if (!(typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))))
                t = typeof(MaybeDisposer.nonDisposer<>).MakeGenericType(types);
            else if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
                t = typeof(MaybeDisposer.StructDisposer<>).MakeGenericType(types);
            else
                t = typeof(MaybeDisposer.ClassDisposer<>).MakeGenericType(types);
            Console.WriteLine("Assigning disposer {0}", t);
            Zap = (ActByRef<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ActByRef<T>), t, "Zap");
            Zap(ref it);
        }
    }
    public static void Zap<T>(ref T it)
    {
        findDisposer<T>.Zap(ref it);
    }
}
```

The first time the code is invoked with any type `T`, it will determine what sort of generic static class can be produced for that parameter and use Reflection to create a delegate to call a static method of that generic class.  Subsequent calls with the same type `T` will use the cached delegate.  Even though Reflection can be a little slow, it will only need to be used once for any type `T`.  All subsequent calls to `MaybeDisposer.Zap<T>(ref T it)` with the same type `T` will be dispatched directly through the delegate and will thus execute quickly.

Note that the calls to `MakeGenericType` will throw exceptions if they are given generic type parameters which do not meet the constraints of the given open generic classes (e.g. if `T` was a class or did not implement `IDisposable`, an attempt to make the generic type `StructDisposer<T>` would throw an exception); such tests occur at run-time and are not validated by the compiler, so you can use run-time checking to see if the types meet appropriate constraints.  Note that the code does not test whether `it` implements `IDisposable`, but instead tests whether `T` does.  This is very important.  Otherwise, if `MaybeDispose` was called with a parameter of type `Object` which held a reference to a `Stream`, it would determine that `it` implemented `IDisposable` and thus try to create a `ClassDisposer<Object>`, crashing because `Object` does not implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest form I can come up with is something like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRecords()
{
    IQueryable<T> entities = new List<T>().AsQueryable();

    if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        entities = FilterMe<IFilterable, T>(entities.OfType<IFilterable>()).AsQueryable();
    }

    return entities;
}

public IEnumerable<TResult> FilterMe<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> linked) where TSource : IFilterable
{
    return linked.Where(r => true).OfType<TResult>();
}
```

The point here is the need to have types to pass into and get back out of the method. I had to change the types locally to get it working.

`OfType` will silently filter out items that are not really of a given type, so it assumes that it's a collection of the same type in any one call.

Because you are re-assigning from `FilterMe`, you still need the interface assignable check.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `OfType(...)` method ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)) what you're looking for?

```
public class MyModel<T> : IModel<T> where T : MyObjectBase
{

    public IQueryable<T> GetRecords()
    {
        var entities = Repository.Query<T>();
        if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            //Filterme is a method that takes in IEnumerable<IFilterable>
            entities = FilterMe(entities));
        }
        return entities;
    }

     public IEnumerable<TResult> FilterMe<TResult>(IEnumerable<TResult> linked) where TResult :  IFilterable
    {
        var dict = GetDict();
        return linked.OfType<TResult>().Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, I assume that method `FilterMe` is used internally and should not be visible outside your model and could be marked `private`. If my assumption is wrong, you could create a private overload of `FilterMe`.

In my answer I just removed the generic `<TResult>`. I assume that this `FilterMe` always is about then entities of type `T` (since it is in the same Model class). This solves the problem about casting between `T` and `TResult`. `TResult` does not have to be marked as `IFilterable` since none of the members of `IFilterable` are used. And since the code already checks if `T` is `IFilterable` why check again (especially when `FilterMe` would be private)?

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetRecords()
    {
        var entities = Repository.Query<T>();
        if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            //Filterme is a method that takes in IEnumerable<IFilterable>
            entities = FilterMe(entities).AsQueryable();
        }
        return entities;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FilterMe(IEnumerable<T> linked) 
    {
        var dict = GetDict();
        return linked.Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id));
    }
```

If you would create a second `FilterMe`, replace the  `IEumerable<T>` types with `Queryable<T>`, so you do not have to convert your entities with `AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> FilterMe<TResult>(IEnumerable<TResult> linked) where TResult : IFilterable
{
    var dict = GetDict();
    return linked.Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id));
}
```

Try replacing FilterMe with this version:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FilterMe(IEnumerable<IFilterable> linked)
{
    var dict = GetDict();
    return linked.Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id)).Cast<T>();
}
```

Then, were you call, change your code to this:

```
if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    //Filterme is a method that takes in IEnumerable<IFilterable>
    var filterable = entities.Cast<IFilterable>();
    entities = FilterMe(entities).AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make the `FilterMe` method a generic method to achieve the same result.

```
    public class MyModel<T> : IModel<T> where T : MyObjectBase {
        public IQueryable<T> GetRecords()
    {
        var entities = Repository.Query<T>();
        if (typeof(IFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            //Filterme is a method that takes in IEnumerable<IFilterable>
            entities = FilterMe(entities.Cast<IFilterable>());
        }
        return entities;
    }

        public IEnumerable<T> FilterMe(IEnumerable<IFilterable> linked)  {
            var dict = GetDict();
            return linked
                    .Where(r => dict.ContainsKey(r.Id))
                    .Cast<T>();
        }
    }
```